# mongo aggregation framework with distinct count of key with mutliple group by

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have reviewed several answers and examples relating to the above topic (including on SO), but couldn't find a working example to use answering my requirements:

I have a collection of documents containing several dimensions (descriptive attributes) and metrics. I wish to count the number of appearances (unique) a certain key value has within a certain group of other keys. i.e. how many players arrived from a country and speak a certain language.

Document structure:

```
{
  "date": "2013-06-13T00:00:00.000Z"
  "Operating System": "Windows 7",
  "Browser": "Chrome",
  "Device": "Desktop/Laptop",
  "Country": "Afghanistan",
  "Language": "English",
  "Player": "91823781188577408" //This is a string value, the player id
},
...
```

Requested result:

```
{
  "Country": "Afghanistan",
  "Language": "English",
  "PlayerCount": 120
}
```

In SQL this would have been something like:

```
SELECT Country, Language, COUNT(DISTINCT PlayerCount) FROM Table 
GROUP BY Country, Language
```

My latest attempt with the aggregation involved $project, $group and $unwind of several types, unfortunately, none worked and there's not much value in adding them. Please note that I'm after a solution based on the aggregation framework and not map-reduce.

Many thanks.

Comment: I guess the sql should be `SELECT Country, Language, COUNT(DISTINCT Player) as PlayerCount FROM Table 
GROUP BY Country, Language`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try:

```
db.YOUR_COLLECTION.aggregate([
    {
        $group: {
            _id: {
                Country: "$Country",
                Language: "$Language"
            },

            PlayerCount: {$sum: 1}
        }
    }
]);
```

Country and Language will be inside "_id" field.

Comment: Hi @MustafaGenç, I'm using the above technique, however there's a small change I wish to implement, what if the above question had `COUNT (Distinct Player)`, how can I change your answer to get the count of players per group?

Comment: Then, use just normal distinct query. No aggregate is needed. http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/command/distinct/

Comment: Thanks @MustafaGenç, that's what I ended up doing, but just out of curiosity, is this something that can be done with agg framework to the best of your knowledge?

Comment: If you run the aggregation query above, size of the AggregationOutput result will give you the count.

Comment: This would not work if I want to get the count of distinct players. If the document had multiple player ids for the same `Country` and `Language`, this would simply give the count of the player ids. How can I get the count of distinct `Player`?

Comment: This helped me a lot. Thanks mate!